# Match specific pattern and print just the matched string in the previous line

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, fastq

I update the question with additional information

I have a .fastq file formatted in the following way

```
@M01790:39:000000000-C3C6P:1:1101:14141:1618 1:N:0:8 (sequence name)
CATCTACATATTCACATATAGACATGAAACACCTGTGGTTCTTCCTC.. (sequence)
+ 
ACCCGGGGGGGGGDGGGFGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGFGFGFF.. (sequence quality)
```

For each sequence the format is the same (repetition of 4 lines)
What I am trying to do is searching for a specific regex pattern ([A-Z]{5,}ACA[A-Z]{5,}ACA[A-Z]{5,})in a window of n=35 characters of the 2nd line, cut it if found and report it at the end of the previous line.

So far I've written a bunch of code that does almost what I want.I thought using the match function together wit the substr of my window of interest but i didn't achieve my goal. I report below the script.awk :

```
match(substr($0,0,35),/regexp/,a) {
    print p,a[0] #print the previous line respect to the matched one
    print #print the current line
    for(i=0;i<=1;i++) { # print the 2 lines following
        getline
        print
    }
}#store previous line 
{ p = $0 }
```

Starting from a file like this:

```
@M01790:39:000000000-C3C6P:1:1101:14141:1618 1:N:0:8 
AACATCTACATATTCACATATAGACATGAAACACCTGTGGTTCTTCCTC.. 
+ 
GGGGGGGGDGGGFGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGFGFGFFGGGGFGF..
```

I would like to obtain an output like this:

```
@M01790:39:000000000-C3C6P:1:1101:14141:1618 1:N:0:8 TATTCACATATAGACATGAAA #is the string that matched the regexp WITHOUT initial AA that doesn' match my expression
ATATTCACATATAGACATGAAACACCTGTGGTTCTTCCTC #without initial AA 
+
GGGFGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGFGFGFFGGGGFGF # without "GGGGGGGGDGGGFGGGGGGFGGG" that is the same number of characters removed in the 2nd line
```

Comment: Darn, I should have said this sooner - never use the word "pattern" in the context of matching as it's highly ambiguous. Always use "string" or "regexp", whichever it is you mean, as each requires a different answer to any given problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    tgtStr   = "pattern"
    tgtLgth  = length(tgtStr)
    winLgth  = 35
    numLines = 4
}
{
    lineNr = ( (NR-1) % numLines ) + 1
    rec[lineNr] = $0
}
lineNr == numLines {
    if ( idx = index(substr(rec[2],1,winLgth),tgtStr) ) {
        rec[1] = rec[1] " " tgtStr
        rec[2] = substr(rec[2],idx+tgtLgth)
        rec[4] = substr(rec[4],idx+tgtLgth)
    }
    for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++ ) {
        print rec[lineNr]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
@M01790:39:000000000-C3C6P:1:1101:14141:1618 1:N:0:8  pattern
ATATTCACATATAGACATGAAACACCTGTGGTTCTTCCTC..
+
GGGFGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGFGFGFFGGGGFGF..
```

wrt the code you posted:

- `substr($0,0,35)` - strings, fields, line numbers, and arrays in awk start at 1 not 0 so that should be `substr($0,1,35)`. Awk will compensate for your mistake and treat it as if you had written 1 instead of 0 in this case but get used to starting everything at `1` to avoid mistakes when it matters.
- `for(i=0;i<=1;i++)` - should be `for(i=1;i<=2;i++)` for the same reason.
- `getline` - not an appropriate use and syntactically fragile, see for(i=0;i<=1;i++)

---

Update - per your comment below that `pattern` is actually a regexp rather than a string:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    tgtRegexp = "[A-Z]{5,}ACA[A-Z]{5,}ACA[A-Z]{5,}"
    winLgth   = 35
    numLines  = 4
}
{
    lineNr = ( (NR-1) % numLines ) + 1
    rec[lineNr] = $0
}
lineNr == numLines {
    if ( match(substr(rec[2],1,winLgth),tgtRegexp) ) {
        rec[1] = rec[1] " " substr(rec[2],RSTART,RLENGTH)
        rec[2] = substr(rec[2],RSTART+RLENGTH)
        rec[4] = substr(rec[4],RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++ ) {
        print rec[lineNr]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dr. Morton. Another brief question.  How should I change the code in order to search for a regular expression? i.e.  [A-Z]{5,}ACA[A-Z]{5,}ACA[A-Z]{5,}. Thanks again for your willingness

Comment: I updated my answer to show a solution for when "pattern" is a regexp - going forward, please don't use the word "pattern" in your code or descriptions, use string or regexp as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. I've tryied the code works almost perfectly. The problem is that the pattern reported at the end of the line is 35 characters instead of 21 (my regular expression length [A-Z]{5,}ACA[A-Z]{5,}ACA[A-Z]{5,}). I've already tryed some solutions using RLENGTH and RSTART but having the very same problem (35 characters instead of 21 are cut and the pattern consist in the search window (that is 35 characters) instead of 21. Where could be the problem ?

Comment: The problem is the example in your question. 1) You're using "pattern" when you mean "regexp" so we can't tell if you want the regexp printed at the end of the first line of the matching block or the string that matches the regexp since they're both "pattern" in your example. 2) your example doesn't actually use regexp metacharacters so we can't tell what you expect to match (e.g. in case of partial matches). It sounds like you have a specific test case that you're having trouble with so update your question to use that as your example instead of the current one that uses "pattern".

Comment: It looks like you just misunderstood what your regexp means. It'll match the whole 35 char substring any time there's 2 "ACA"s 5 or more chars apart. I suspect you meant to use `{5}` instead of `{5,}` as the RE intervals.

Comment: Dr. Morton, Thanks for answering to my awk questions. I answer here so make things easy. I am trying to use our script for regexp but I am trying to add another expression to search. The problem is that is at the end of the string and I would like to use the same approach to report the string extracted removing the part which matches.

Comment: It's been months since this question, rather than adding requirements now in a comment please just post a new followup question with it's own concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: I re-posted the original problems with all the details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707588/match-specific-pattern-and-print-just-the-matched-string-in-the-previous-line-u

Answer (score 0):

I warn you, I wanted to have some fun and it is twisted.

```
awk -v pattern=pattern -v window=15 '
BEGIN{RS="@";FS=OFS="\n"}
{pos = match($2, pattern); n_del=pos+length(pattern)}
pos && (n_del<=window){$1 = $1 " " pattern; $2=substr($2, n_del); $4=substr($4, n_del)}
NR!=1{printf "%s%s", RS, $0}
' file
```

Input :

```
@M01790:39:000000000-C3C6P:1:1101:14141:1618 1:N:0:8
CATCTACpatternATATTCACATATAGACATGAAACACCTGTGGTTCTTCCTC..
+
ACCCGGGGGGGGGDGGGFGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGFGFGFFGGGGFGF..
@M01790:39:000000000-C3C6P:1:1101:14141:1618 1:N:0:8
CATCTACGCpatternATATTCACATATAGACATGAAACACCTGTGGTTCTTCCTC..
+
ACCCGGGGDGGGGGGDGGGFGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGFGFGFFGGGGFGF..
```

Output :

```
@M01790:39:000000000-C3C6P:1:1101:14141:1618 1:N:0:8 pattern
ATATTCACATATAGACATGAAACACCTGTGGTTCTTCCTC.. 
+ 
GGGFGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGFGFGFFGGGGFGF..
@M01790:39:000000000-C3C6P:1:1101:14141:1618 1:N:0:8 
CATCTACGCpatternATATTCACATATAGACATGAAACACCTGTGGTTCTTCCTC.. 
+ 
ACCCGGGGDGGGGGGDGGGFGGGGGGFGGGGGGGGGGGFGGGGFGFGFFGGGGFGF..
```

Second block is not updated because window is 15 and it cannot find the pattern within this window.

I used variable `RS` to deal with entire 4 lines block with `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$4`. Because input file starts with `RS` and does not end with `RS`, I prefered to not set `ORS` and use `printf` instead of `print`.

Comment: I've tryied the code with a larger file, but it gives me the wrong output, i.e. duplicated rows etc.

Comment: @FilippoVit Is it possible that some blocks do not start with @ ? Without any additional information it is hard to say.